# XcodeGen generated single-target (iOS16 Xcode14) watchOS app not working

Tags: xcode, ios16, xcode14, xcodegen

I found that the newly (iOS16 Xcode 14) introduced single-target watchOS app does not work when I try to implement it with XcodeGen.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Prepare build
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/martin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WatchTestGen-eqtccuxbzqoyuncgwdiwyamlfkpb/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchTestWatch Watch App.app/WatchTestWatch Watch App'
    note: Target 'WatchTestWatch Watch App' (project 'WatchTestGen'): CopyAndPreserveArchs /Users/martin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WatchTestGen-eqtccuxbzqoyuncgwdiwyamlfkpb/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchTestWatch Watch App.app/WatchTestWatch Watch App
    note: Target 'WatchTestWatch Watch App' (project 'WatchTestGen') has a command with output '/Users/martin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WatchTestGen-eqtccuxbzqoyuncgwdiwyamlfkpb/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchTestWatch Watch App.app/WatchTestWatch Watch App'


Multiple commands produce '/Users/martin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WatchTestGen-eqtccuxbzqoyuncgwdiwyamlfkpb/Build/Products/Debug-watchsimulator/WatchTestWatch Watch App.app/WatchTestWatch Watch App'

Build failed    2022-08-30 16:41    1.2 seconds
```

I created a sample project with the failing `project.yml` here: https://github.com/MartinP7r/xcodegen-watch-sample

`WatchTest.xcodeproj` works fine while the generated `WatchTestGen.xcodeproj` does not.

This requires Xcode 14 beta.

I'd be very happy about any advice on where to look for errors in my project or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working. It seems like the target type should simply be `application`, not `application.watchapp2` .

```
type: application
platform: watchOS
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. I did this too https://github.com/MartinP7r/xcodegen-watch-sample/blob/e69a6b7f6d016f8330ac0abc6472e96f164672f3/project.yml#L21